# How to set frequency of capturing screenshots in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to set a defined frequency of screenshots capturing in the Chrome DevTools Network tab. Do you know if it is possible ?

I also do not understand why DevTools generate different number of screenshots each time I refresh a web site (ex. http://www.tomshardware.com/).

Thanks,
Rafal